# Auto test with random keys from dict with added values equal to a certain number

Tags: python, automation, test-automation

I have a list (23 items) of choices and I've transformed it into a dictionary in order to have a value for each choice.

I need to select 3 random choices from that dictionary each time I run the test and their value sum has to be 23.

Until now I did this:

```
list = ['somthing', 'something else'......'something else else']
nums = [1,2,3...23]
dic = dict(zip(lista, nums))

for x, y, z in dic:
    if dic.values(x) + dic.values(y) + dic.values(z) == 23:
        print(x, y, z)
```

and I get that there are too many values to unpack.

Any idea how I can get this done?

Comment: What did you expect `for x, y, z in dic` to do? Given the keys come from the first list, that's effectively e.g. `x, y, z = 'something'`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i got some help and i had to use a while statement. Posting the code bellow maybe someone will find it helpful.

```
while True:

key1 = random.choice(list(dic.keys()))
key2 = random.choice(list(dic.keys()))
key3 = random.choice(list(dic.keys()))

listSum = dic[key1] + dic[key2] + dic[key3]
if listSum == 23:
    print(key1, key2, key3)
    break
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601